# Why is 224 bit ecdsa faster than 192 bit ecdsa?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, openssl, performance

I ran several benchmarks using `openssl` on 2 different computers and I got a surprising result.

for the Nist 192 bit curve the benchmark result is

```
>openssl speed ecdsap192
                              sign    verify    sign/s verify/s
 192 bit ecdsa (nistp192)   0.0001s   0.0003s  11980.6   3481.6
```

for the Nist 224 bit curve the benchmark result is

```
>openssl speed ecdsap224
                              sign    verify    sign/s verify/s
 224 bit ecdsa (nistp224)   0.0001s   0.0001s  13740.5   6948.8
```

So verifying a nistp224 ecdsa signature is twice faster than with nistp192.

I really expected nistp224 to be slower as it handles bigger numbers.
Why isn't it so?

Comment: Implementers put a lot of effort into speeding up the variants we use in practice. For example the paper [Emilia Käsper - Fast Elliptic Curve Cryptography in OpenSSL](https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/37376.pdf) presents an optimized P224 implementation.

Comment: It's not just P-192 that is inefficient. P-256 is _significantly_ faster than P-384, to the point where one of my servers started choking up when using P-384, but not when using P-256 or even P-521.

Comment: Heh, my machine reports 0.0000s for P256 sign. Fortunately we still have the sign/s :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both curves have similar form and primes close to powers of two ($2^{192}-2^{64}-1$ and $2^{224} - 2^{96} + 1$), so you wouldn't expect large differences in performance – all things equal, P-224 might be anywhere from 30%  to 60% slower due to the computational scaling of curve operations.

However, in practice different implementations will have different performance and some curves' will be better optimized. In [this case](https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html) it looks like P-192 might only have a 32-bit portable implementation and P-224 an optimized 64-bit one:

> **Changes between 1.0.0h and 1.0.1  [14 Mar 2012]**
>
> [...]  Add optional 64-bit optimized implementations of elliptic curves NIST-P224, NIST-P256, NIST-P521, with constant-time single point multiplication on typical inputs. [...]

<sub>(Note: I haven't actually checked if P-192 is unoptimized. You should do it with your version if you are interested.)</sub>

As for why they would optimize P-224 better, it is the minimal acceptable size according to e.g. [NIST recommendations](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-131A/sp800-131A.pdf). Doesn't make much sense to spend time optimizing something that's recommended not to be used.

Comment: Based on the size, P224 should be 50-60% more expensive since the size of the exponent increases as well. So the scaling has an exponent between 2.6 and 3 depending on the multiplication algorithm.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, yeah, I'll fix the percentage. Of course, it's a theoretical number that assumes exponentiation takes 100% of the time and the CPU isn't limited by e.g. cache effects, etc.